# function/method in a collection initializer c#

Tags: c#, collections, expression, collection-initializer

can i insert a method/function in a collection initializer? i am trying to insert expression in the function within a collection initializer but the variable in the class is asking for the declaration of it's body. Thank you.

```
            List<demo> ags = new List<demo>()
            {
                new demo { acst = "One", currUpd() = () =>  { intba += totint; } ,  st = 1 < 2},
                new demo { acst = "Two", currUpd() = () =>  { intba += intp; } = 0,  st = 1 < 2 },
                new demo { acst = "Three", currUpd() = () =>  { intba += pp; },  st = 1 < 2 }
            };


            var agss = ags.Select(x => new {acst = x.acst, currUpd = x.currUpd, st = x.st });
            foreach (var item in agss)
            {
                if (item.st == true)
                {
                    item.currUpd();

                }
            }


            public class demo
            {
            public string acst { get; set; }
            public delegate void currUpd() { get; set; }
            public bool st { get; set; }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a delegate property like that. Declare it as an `Action` instead:

```
    public Action currUpd { get; set; }
```

now you can do:

```
List<demo> ags = new List<demo>()
{
    new demo { acst = "One", currUpd = () =>  { intba += totint; } ,  st = 1 < 2},
    new demo { acst = "Two", currUpd = () =>  { intba += intp; },  st = 1 < 2 },
    new demo { acst = "Three", currUpd = () =>  { intba += pp; },  st = 1 < 2 }
};
```

I assume the `= 0` on the second `demo` was a typo